# tempCodeRunnerFile.py problem in visual sudio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I had this problem since I started using the code runner extension. a file called `tempCodeRunnerFile.py` get created and runs when I click on the run button it really annoying, I tried deleting the `tempCodeRunnerFile.py` file but it keeps coming back.

Comment: Where is the file getting created? Why are you blanking out the filepath?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it gets created in the same file where my actual code is.

Comment: @Kunal Shah my code works fine, the error is no related to my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indicates that you have selected part of the code snippet and run it.

You can add `"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true` in the settings.json file to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

If your highlighting your code. Dont highlight it. Just run the code without highlighting any code. and it will work.